# SQL - Interchange rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a case where I need to interchange the rows and columns. Yes , I tried with Pivot and UnPivot which doesnt give me the desired outcome.

My source table :

```
+-------+------+------+-----+-----+
| month | year | po1  | po2 | po3 |
+-------+------+------+-----+-----+
| Jan   | 2013 |  100 |  20 |  10 |
| Feb   | 2014 | 1100 | 120 | 110 |
+-------+------+------+-----+-----+
```

I was able to make a static pivot

```
select Description,value from #test
unpivot (value for Description in (year,po1, po2, po3)) unpiv;
```

This is the result I'm able to generate

```
+-------------+-------+
| Description | value |
+-------------+-------+
| year        |  2013 |
| po1         |   100 |
| po2         |    20 |
| po3         |    10 |
| year        | 12013 |
| po1         |  1100 |
| po2         |   120 |
| po3         |   110 |
+-------------+-------+
```

Expected output :

```
+------+------+------+
| Desc | Jan  | Feb  |
+------+------+------+
| year | 2013 | 2014 |
| po1  |  100 | 1100 |
| po2  |   20 |  120 |
| po3  |   10 |  110 |
+------+------+------+
```

Further, the rows / columns would keep changing, is there a way to make it dynamic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server dynamic PIVOT query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1):

This sort of transpose is a pain -- requiring pivoting and unpivoting.  Here is one method:

```
select v.description,
       max(case when t.month = 'Jan' then v.value end) as Jan,
       max(case when t.month = 'Feb' then v.value end) as Feb
from #test t cross apply
     (values ('year', t.year), ('p01', p01), ('p02', p02), ('p03', p03)
     ) v(description, value) 
group by v.description;
```

Comment: Yes sir, such pain. Thanks though, but is there a way to do it dynamically?

Comment: @Chendur if there's a way to do it statically, there's a way to do it dynamically. You just need to make full use of T-SQL! Happy coding!

Comment: @Chendur . . . Copying lines for 12 months seems much simpler to me than a dynamic expression.

Comment: @JohnBell Totaly, but any leads would be much helpful

Comment: @Chendur  . . . More specifically, this answers the question that you have asked.  If you want a dynamic version, then ask another question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The actual table has 200 odd columns :(  Example posted here was to portray my query in a simple way

Comment: @Chendur . . . As I say, ask another question.